# Cached variables not being stored in VSTO Excel workbook

Tags: excel, caching, vsto, excel-2007

I have a VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) workbook with several cached variables. The relevant code for one of these is:

```
Public Class ThisWorkbook
    <Cached()>
    Public RetentionPC As Double

    Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Startup(sender as Object, e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        If Not IsCached(RetentionPC) then
            RetentionPC = 0.5
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This code runs and the value of the property is set, but it does not persist when the workbook is saved.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you will be able to store cached values like that. If you wish to store information I would recommend using custom properties (either `CustomProperties` on a Worksheet or `CustomDocumentProperties` on a Workbook, depending on what you need).

Another way would be to store information to User or Application settings. This would store it across multiple Workbooks:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms250653